# Detecting trapezium, rhombus, square, quadrilateral, parallelogram by Opencv in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I've written a code like this to detect the shapes present in a png image. I get correct output for detecting a square and rectangle but for other shapes like Trapezium, rhombus, quadrilateral and parallelogram I am not able to detect it correctly. What is the correct code to detect these different types of polygon?

```
_,thrash=cv2.threshold(imgGray,240,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours,_=cv2.findContours(thrash,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:

    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)

    cv2.drawContours(img,[approx],0,(0,0,0),5)

    x=approx.ravel()[0]

    y=approx.ravel()[1]

    if len(approx)==4:

        x1,y1,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(approx)

        aspectRatio=float(w)/h

        print(aspectRatio)

        if aspectRatio>=0.95 and aspectRatio<=1.05:

            cv2.putText(img,"Square",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0))

        else:

            cv2.putText(img,"Rectangle",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0))
```

Comment: I would look up the properties of your described shapes. So for example a general quadrilateral is existent if the sum of interior angles equals 360°. `approx` already stores the four corners. After that you could categorize the quadrilaterals like you already did for a square (aspect ratios, parallelity,size of interior angles etc.)

Comment: Perhaps this will help. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/